# Jquery code not filtering the contents taken from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to successfully get the complete table from a different page and display it on the current page. I am trying to filter them base on the manufacturer's name but all rows are still being displayed. can anyone help me please? see my code below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get("https://vst-wf.webflow.io/all-products-page", function(data) {
  var extractedContent = $(data).find("#main-collection").html();
  $("#display-content").html(extractedContent);
});
});

var cameraItems = $(".camera-selector-row"); 
console.log(cameraItems);
cameraItems.each(function() {
console.log($(this).find(".data_manu > div").text().trim());
var manufacturer = $(this).find(".data_manu > div").text().trim();
if (manufacturer !== "Vieworks") {
  $(this).hide();
}
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you do not get CORS errors, if you do, then you need to grab their data on your server using a proxy
2. You need to execute the filtering where you get the data - the $.get is async so your code needs to be in the callback

This works  - I have mocked some of the data

When you are happy, remove

`var extractedContent = $("#data").find(".w-dyn-item").filter(function() {`

and the comments from the $.get

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//  $.get("https://vst-wf.webflow.io/all-products-page", function(data) {
    //var extractedContent = $(data).find(".w-dyn-item").filter(function() {
    var extractedContent = $("#data").find(".w-dyn-item").filter(function() {
      var manufacturer = $(this).find(".data_manu div").text().trim();
      console.log(manufacturer)
      return manufacturer === "Vieworks";
    });
    $("#display-content").html(extractedContent); // must be here to work
//  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="display-content"></div>
<div id="data">
    <div fs-cmscombine-element="list" role="list" class="w-dyn-items" hidden>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VT-3K7X-H250</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>3200 × 128</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>250 kHz</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">CXP-6 2 Lanes</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>7.0 × 7.0</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8/10/12 bits</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Color</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VT-3K7X-E250</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>3200 × 32</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>250 kHz</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">CXP-6 2 Lanes</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>7.0 × 7.0</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8/10/12 bits</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Mono</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VT-3K7G-H38</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>3200 × 128</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>38 kHz</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">GigE</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>7.0 × 7.0</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8/10/12 bits</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Color</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VT-3K7G-E38</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>3200 × 32</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>38 kHz</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">GigE</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>7.0 × 7.0</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8/10/12 bits</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Color</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VT-3K7C-H100</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>3200 × 128</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>100 kHz</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">Camera Link</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>7.0 × 7.0</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8/10/12 bits</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Color</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VT-3K7C-E100</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>3200 × 32</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>100 kHz</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">Camera Link</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>7.0 × 7.0</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8/10/12 bits</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Color</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VT-23K3.5X-H100</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>23360 × 256</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>100 kHz</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">CXP-6 4 Lanes</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>3.5 × 3.5</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8/10/12 bits</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Mono</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VQ-1600G2-M 77 H</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div>1.5</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>1440 × 1080</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>77</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>IMX 273</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">GigE</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>5.5 × 5.5</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8 / 10 / 12 / 16 bit</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Mono</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VQ-1600G2-C 77 H</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div>1.5</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>1440 × 1080</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>77</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>IMX 273</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">GigE</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>6.9 × 6.9</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8 / 10 / 12 / 16 bit</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Color</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd05f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">VQ-12MG2-M 10 H</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd061-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div>12</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd063-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>4096 × 3000</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd065-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>9.9</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd067-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>IMX 304</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd069-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">GigE</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>3.45 × 3.45</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8 / 10 / 12 / 16 bit</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd06f-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>Vieworks</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd071-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd073-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd075-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd077-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd079-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07b-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-d08c0ee3-a067-7d8a-8c4b-edd33babd07d-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Mono</div></div></div></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="camera-selector-row w-dyn-item"><div class="w-layout-grid selector-table-item-row area-data-table"><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd4772110f8-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block first data_model_name"><div class="left-align">exo183MGE</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd4772110fa-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_mp"><div>20.2</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd4772110fc-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_res_h_v"><div>5496 × 3672</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd4772110fe-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_fps"><div>6</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211100-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_sensor_type"><div>IMX 183</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211102-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_interface"><div class="left-align">GigE</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211104-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_size"><div>2.4 × 2.4</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211106-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block data_pixel_data"><div>8 / 12 bit</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211108-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block last data_manu"><div>SVS-Vistek</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd47721110a-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block shutter data_shutter"><div class="w-dyn-bind-empty"></div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd47721110c-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block pixel-shift data_pixel_shift"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd47721110e-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block cooling data_cooling"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211110-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block tdi data_tdi"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211112-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_area_scan"><div class="w-embed">true</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211114-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_line_scan"><div class="w-embed">false</div></div><div id="w-node-b28ada7a-cb67-e4f5-e780-ecd477211116-7ebf3181" class="table-heading-block area-scan data_chroma"><div class="w-embed">Mono</div></div></div></div></div>

</div>
```